# Transpiling node-fetch require returns error

Tags: ecmascript-6, transpiler, node-fetch

I'm running into an issue with the `node-fetch` library.
The new version (3.0.3) has `"type": "module"` in its package.json. This is a problem because I transpile my code from ES6 to regular js which uses `require` and then I get `...firebase_datasource.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.`
I can use an earlier version of `node-fetch` that doesn't contain `"type": "module"` in its package.json in its package.json, but that's not a solution.
What's the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`node-fetch`'s README](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#commonjs) explains what to do:

> #### CommonJS
>
> `node-fetch` from v3 is an ESM-only module - you are not able to import it with `require()`.
>
> If you cannot switch to ESM, please use v2 which remains compatible with CommonJS. Critical bug fixes will continue to be published for v2.
>
> ```sh
> npm install node-fetch@2
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can use the async `import()` function from CommonJS to load `node-fetch` asynchronously:
>
> ```js
> // mod.cjs
> const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));
> ```

Comment: Thank you, totally missed that!